# Authorization Header Not Found in CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Tags: php, curl

I'm creating an API with PHP using Authorization Bearer Token

here's the code when calling

```
$apiUrl = 'https://anabatic.com/api/usersapi.php?op=view';
$token = '2E59DDE3B0700F63055A0F1BCB6D2FEB';

$ch = curl_init($apiUrl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        print_r($data);
    } else {
        echo 'Error decoding JSON: ' . json_last_error_msg();
        echo PHP_EOL . 'Body Respons: ' . $response;
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
```

when run it appears error Authorization Header Not Found

can you help me

Thank you

Comment: do I have to add module headers in my CWP?